# How do I alter the enum alternatives?

Tags: postgresql

I have defined a new type in Postgres:

`CREATE TYPE PROJECT_STATUS AS ENUM ('draft', 'accepting_members', 'ongoing', 'completed');`

Now, I would like to change the `accepting_members` to be called `ongoing_accepting`

If I understand Postgres correctly, the `ALTER TYPE` should help me. I tried this:

```
mypostgresproject=# SELECT version();
                                                     version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.0 (Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

mypostgresproject=# \dT
          List of data types
 Schema |      Name      | Description
--------+----------------+-------------
 public | project_status |
(1 row)

mypostgresproject=# SELECT
    pg_type.typname,
     pg_enum.enumlabel
FROM
    pg_type
JOIN
    pg_enum ON pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid;
    typname     |     enumlabel
----------------+-------------------
 project_status | draft
 project_status | accepting_members
 project_status | ongoing
 project_status | stopped
(4 rows)

mypostgresproject=# ALTER TYPE project_status RENAME ATTRIBUTE accepting_members TO ongoing_accepting CASCADE;
ERROR:  relation "project_status" does not exist
mypostgresproject=#
```

What should I do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html) says

> RENAME ATTRIBUTE
> This form is only usable with composite types. It changes the name of an individual attribute of the type.

> RENAME VALUE
> This form renames a value of an enum type. The value's place in the enum's ordering is not affected. An error will occur if the
> specified value is not present or the new name is already present.

So since you are working on an enum, you must use `rename value`, and since the value is a string it must be quoted:

```
ALTER TYPE project_status RENAME VALUE 'accepting_members' TO 'ongoing_accepting';
```